# Elegant template specialization

Tags: c++, templates

Is there an elegant way to specialize a template based on one of its template parameters?

Ie.

```
template<int N> struct Junk {
    static int foo() {
        // stuff
        return Junk<N - 1>::foo();
    }
};

// compile error: template argument '(size * 5)' involves template parameter(s)
template<int N> struct Junk<N*5> {
    static int foo() {
        // stuff
        return N;
    }
};

template<> struct Junk<0> {
    static int foo() {
        // stuff
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Ie. I am trying to specialize a template based on the parameter being divisible by 5. The only way I can seem to do it is like below:

```
template<int N> struct JunkDivisibleBy5 {
    static int foo() {
        // stuff
        return N;
    }
};

template<int N> struct Junk {
    static int foo() {
        // stuff
        if ((N - 1) % 5 == 0 && N != 1)
            return JunkDivisibleBy5<N - 1>::foo();
        else
            return Junk<N - 1>::foo();
    }
};


template<> struct Junk<0> {
    static int foo() {
        // stuff
        return 0;
    }
};
```

But this is significantly less elegant, and also necessitates instantiation of all templates even if the template argument shouldn't require it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How's this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template < typename T, T N, T D >
struct fraction {
    typedef T value_type;
    static const value_type num = N;
    static const value_type denom = D;
    static const bool is_div = (num % denom == 0);
};

template< typename T, T N, T D, bool P >
struct do_if {
    static void op() { cout << N << " NOT divisible by " << D << endl; }
};

template< typename T, T N, T D >
struct do_if< T, N, D, true > {
    static void op() { cout << N << " divisible by " << D << endl; }
};

template < int N >
void foo() {
    typedef fraction< int, N, 5 > f;
    do_if< typename f::value_type, f::num, f::denom, f::is_div >::op();
}

int main() {
    foo< -5 >();
    foo< -1 >();
    foo< 0 >();
    foo< 1 >();
    foo< 5 >();
    foo< 10000005 >();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I compiled it, ran it and verified the test results.  I included the entire program so others can do the same.

Comment: not with g++ 4.1.3

meta_programming.cpp:10: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope struct my<N>
meta_programming.cpp:10: error: enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized

Comment: CLARIFICATION: I compiled it with Visual C++ 2008, ran it and verified the test results.

Comment: Sorry @David Nehme, I don't use g++.  If you have a g++ compatible solution, please post it because I'd like to learn more about what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I re-worked this to (hopefully) be more acceptable to g++.  It still works fine with VC9.  @David Nehme, can you report success/failure on g++?

Comment: I tried w/ g++ 4.3.3: no dice :(
~$ g++ metaprog.cpp -o metaprog
metaprog.cpp: In function ‘void foo()’:
metaprog.cpp:25: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class T, T N, T D, bool P> struct do_if’
metaprog.cpp:25: error:   expected a type, got ‘f::value_type’
metaprog.cpp:25: error: ‘<type error>’ is not a valid type for a template constant parameter
metaprog.cpp:25: error: ‘<type error>’ is not a valid type for a template constant parameter
metaprog.cpp:25: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token

Comment: put typename before f::value_type. f::value_type is a dependent type.

Comment: @MattJ, I edited as per @litb's suggestion (I also shortened 'numerator' to 'num' and 'denominator' to 'denom' to avoid a horizontal scrollbar).  Does this help?

Answer (score 7):

Using D programming language templates, one could write it as:

```
struct Junk(int N)
{
    static int foo()
    {
        static if (N == 0)
            return 0;
        else static if ((N % 5) == 0)
            return N;
        else
            return Junk!(N - 1).foo();
    }
}
```

static if's are executed at compile time.

Comment: I shouldn't upvote this, but I did because it suddenly makes me want to learn D :)

Answer (score 5):

All calculations could be made in compile-time:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N> struct Junk {
    enum { IsDivisibleBy5 = (N % 5 == 0) };
    template<bool D> struct JunkInternal {
        enum { Result = Junk<N-1>::Result };
    };
    template<> struct JunkInternal<true> {
        enum { Result = N };
    };
    enum { Result = JunkInternal<IsDivisibleBy5>::Result };
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    std::cout << Junk< 0 >::Result << std::endl;
    std::cout << Junk< 7 >::Result << std::endl;
    std::cout << Junk< 10 >::Result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Code

```
template<int A, bool = !(A % 5)>
struct select : select<A-1> { };

template<int A>
struct select<A, true> { static int const value = A; };

template<>
struct select<0, true> { static int const value = 0; };

int main() {
    std::cout << select<1>::value; // 0
    std::cout << select<7>::value; // 5
    std::cout << select<10>::value; // 10
}
```

Keep the divisor variable

```
template<int A, int D, bool = !(A % D)>
struct select : select<A-1, D> { };

template<int A, int D>
struct select<A, D, true> { static int const value = A; };

template<int D>
struct select<0, D, true> { static int const value = 0; };

int main() {
    std::cout << select<1, 3>::value; // 0
    std::cout << select<7, 3>::value; // 6
    std::cout << select<10, 3>::value; // 9
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance works quite well:

```
template<int N> struct Junk : private JunkBase < N % 5 > { };

template<int N> struct JunkBase {
    static int foo() {
        // stuff
        return Junk<N - 1>::foo();
    }
};
template< > struct JunkBase<0> {
    static int foo() {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

You might need to pass N to JunkBase::foo, if you need N/5 too.

Answer (score 0):

I would hardly call it elegant, but here's my version of your code using only templates for computation (along with a test thing) --

```
#include <iostream>

template < int N > struct JunkDivBy5 {
    static int foo() {
        return N;
    }
};

template < int N > struct Junk {
    template < int N1 > struct _JunkCond {
        enum { val = ( N1 != 1 && ( N1 - 1 ) % 5 == 0 ) ? 1 : 0 };
    };

    template < int M, int N1 > struct _JunkBranch { /* Error */ };

    template < int N1 > struct _JunkBranch< 1, N1 > {
        typedef JunkDivBy5< N1 - 1 > Type;
    };

    template < int N1 > struct _JunkBranch< 0, N1 > {
        typedef Junk< N1 - 1 > Type;
    };

    static int foo() {
        return _JunkBranch< _JunkCond< N >::val, N >::Type::foo();
    }
};

template <> struct Junk< 0 > {
    static int foo() {
        return 0;
    }
};

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    std::cout << Junk< 0 >::foo() << std::endl;
    std::cout << Junk< 5 >::foo() << std::endl;
    std::cout << Junk< 7 >::foo() << std::endl;
    std::cout << Junk< 25 >::foo() << std::endl;
}
```