# Partial Specialization Question

Tags: c++

I need a fresh pair of eyes.

This is obviously illegal, but it shows what I'm trying to do:

```
template <typename T, T> struct Foo
{
};

template <typename T> struct Foo <T, 0> //Obviously I can't do this.
{
};
```

Is there any way to wrap T or do something tricky so that this sort of thing can work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can use this trick:

```
template <typename T, T, T=0> struct Foo {
};

template <typename T, T t> struct Foo <T, t, t> {
};
```

If t is 0 in the specialization, it will match the default argument, and the specialization is taken. Otherwise, the primary template is taken.

**Edit**: What the heck does the third parameter mean? Well, it's a default and it's 0. It will be passed when we name the specialization `Foo<int, 5>` for example. But really, we instantiate a template with the arguments `Foo<int, 5, 0>`, because the last is a default argument. The partial specialization matches, when the third parameter matches the third argument, which is zero by default, and if the third and second arguments are the same, because both are `t`.

The above trick has the drawback that also `Foo<int, 9, 9>` uses our specialization. But on the other side, the above is remarkable simple, so that you can probably get away with that. If you don't want that to work, then you can use `enable_if`, which is a bit more complicated:

```
template <typename T, T, typename = void> struct Foo {
};

template <typename T, T t> 
struct Foo <T, t, typename boost::enable_if_c< t == 0 >::type> {
};
```

Now, even if you say `Foo<int, 9, void>`, our partial specialization won't be chosen, because the condition `t == 0` isn't true, and `::type` will thus not be available. SFINAE doesn't chose the specialization then. Of course, with this enable_if solution, you are not limited to t being zero. Any condition will do. For reference, here is the code of enable_if, if you don't use boost. Cut the `_c` suffix above then, which we don't need for the version below:

```
template<bool C, typename T = void>
struct enable_if {
  typedef T type;
};

template<typename T>
struct enable_if<false, T> { };
```

Comment: The third argument is there just to get a value 0 of type T in it.

If you wanted to specialize for two values (like 0 and 1), you would have to use a type argument as described in the documentation of boost::enable_if, am I right?

Comment: yeah, exactly. like the one here, the conditions must be disjunct, so that you don't get ambiguities: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267418/elegant-template-specialization#275254